# Can i use composite primary key here?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below are my two tables

```
Student(rno int primary key,name varchar(20))

Fees(id int identity,name varchar(10), amount decimal(10,2), pdate date,
rno int foreign key references Student(rno))
```

In `Fees` table `[id name rno]` gives unique.

So can i create composite primary key on table `Fees`? or need to add one more table to normalize? 
Most of the search on table `Fees` is based on column `rno`. So it would be good if i have index on `rno`.

Comment: Is having 3 column good idea when considering performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Composite Primary Key if you want to be **unique set of (id,rno)** by below code

```
create table my_table (
     column_a integer not null,
     column_b integer not null,
     column_c varchar(50),
     primary key (column_a, column_b)
);
```

once you create composite primary key constraint you won't able to insert **duplicate  combination of rno and id**

Answer (score 0):

create one more table of FeesMaster where you entered the which type of fees and its name, if any due, then the price or other details.

**This will help in future expansion.**

and give reference the FeesMaster id to Fees as FeesID. Always give primary key to auto-increment if it is numeric field.

So your table like this.

```
Student(rno int primary key with auto-increment,name varchar(20))

FeesMaster(feesid int primary key with auto-increment,name varchar(20), price int, dueprice int) --last 2 is optional or give other detail which work as a master detail

--use this table as a transaction table of both above master table, the logic is
Fees(
id int identity, 
rno int foreign key references Student(rno),
feesid id foreign key references FeesMaster(FeesID), 
amount decimal(10,2), 
pdate date)
```

Updated :-

```
Fees
    id is primary-key of Fees table which are auto-increment
    rno is refernce-key of Student table's rno column
    feesid is refernce-key of FeesMaster table's feesid column
```

So in insert gives the feesid of fees master based on fees name. and to get data, the query looklike

```
select s.name as studentname, fm.name as feesname
from student s
inner join Fees f on f.rno = s.rno
inner join FeesMaster fm on f.feesid = fm.feesid
```

Comment: So here (id,rno) is primary key on table Fees. Isn't?

Comment: there is no index on column rno. Then how can i search 'Fees' table based on 'rno'. As i said, mostly i use 'rno' to search 'Fees' table.